# Error while opening django shell - ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when I try to open django shell.

python manage.py shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/VirtualEnv/ChatterBox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/VirtualEnv/ChatterBox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/VirtualEnv/ChatterBox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/VirtualEnv/ChatterBox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/VirtualEnv/ChatterBox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: Are you in your virtualenv ?

Answer (score 3):

seems like you have `request` in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using linux run 
 $ sudo pip install requests if you have pip installed